# Output argument "y" (and maybe others) not assigned during call

Tags: matlab

I have this task:

Write a Matlab function named multioperations which returns the following output on graph simultaneously.
a. Amplitude scaled signal
Alpha, beta, gamma are the variables used for defining the scales for shifting, time scaling and amplitude scaling respectively. Take the input signal Asin(2π fn +φ ) . Alpha,beta and gamma must be taken from user on run time.

This is my code:

```
    function [y,l]=multioperators(x,n)        
    prompt = 'Enter value for Shifting:\n Alpha=';
    alpha = input(prompt);
    a=alpha;
    function [u,k]=sigshift(x,n,a)        
    k=n+a;
    u=x;
    end
    prompt = 'Enter value for Time Scaling:\n Beta = ';
    beta = input(prompt);
    b=beta;
    function [s,t]=sigscale(u,k,b)        
    t=b/k;        
    s=u;   
    end
    prompt = 'Enter value for Amplitude Scaling:\n Gamma = ';
    gamma = input(prompt);
    c=gamma;   
    function[q,r]= sigamp(s,t,c)        
    r=t;        
    q=c*s;      
    end
    end
```

But when I call this function as follows I get an error:

```
    A=2;
    n=-10:0.01:10;
    phi=pi/2;
    f=0.01;
    x=A*sin(2*pi*f*n+phi);
    subplot(2,1,1);
    plot(n,x);
    [y,l]=multioperators(x,n);
    subplot(2,1,2)  
    plot(l,y)
```

I get the following error:

```
     Error in multioperators (line 3)
     prompt = 'Enter value for Shifting:\n Alpha=';

     Output argument "y" (and maybe others) not
     assigned during call to
    "C:\Users\mehak_raibail\Documents\MATLAB\multioperators.m>multioperators".

    Error in ex8_q3a (line 8)
    [y,l]=multioperators(x,n);
```

Please give some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never assign a value to the variable `y` (nor `l` for that matter), yet you expect it as an output when you call `[y,l]=multioperators(x,n);`.

Furthermore, you have nested functions that you never call. You may want to look at the [doc](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html).

Comment: thanx a lot, the document helped